# Using Doctrine ORM with namespaces

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, composer-php

Official guide explains how to use Doctrine ORM with `/src` directory and it works okay, however, I have a project with a structure like this:

```
vendor/
src/
 Entities/
  Category.php
public/
 .htaccess
 index.php
bootstrap.php
cli-config.php
composer.json
```

And I want to have namespace `App` so I can do this from `public/index.php`:

```
use App\DB\Entities\Category;
```

How should I configure `autoload` option and `bootstrap.php` to do this? Composer file currently has this autoloader:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": "/src/Entities" 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should update your autoload section in the composer.json file with this configuration:

```
"autoload" : {
    "psr-4" : {
        "App\\DB\\Entities\\" : "src/entities/",
    }
}
```

And your entity class should look like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\DB\Entities;

class Category
{
    function __construct(){
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, following what [composer's documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4) says you should have something like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "./src"
    }
}
```

and `Category.php` must be created like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entities;

class Category
{

}
```

[Folder structure example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7v8C.png)